# How to populate an Ext.dataview.List from the Control using a Store in Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need to populate dynamically a `Ext.dataview.List` with some value from a `Store` when a method will be called in the `Controller`. Any idea how to do it? With my following code I can see `Ext.dataview.List` empty. When debugging I can see `storeEvents2` is populated correctly.

Please provide me a sampe of code if possible.

```
populateViewsAfterLogIn: function (){
    var me = this;
    debugger
    var storeEvents2 =  Ext.getStore('Events2');
    storeEvents2.load();
    storeEvents2.sync();
    var myEventsList = me.getEventsList();
    myEventsList.initialize();
    myEventsList.data(storeEvents2);



},
```

---

STORE

```
Ext.define('XXX.store.Events2',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],

    config:{
        model: 'XXX.model.Event2',
        proxy:{

            type:'jsonp',
            url: Configurations.listAllTimetableEventsCustom,
            reader:'json'
        },
        autoLoad:true,

        sorters: [{ property: 'DateTimeStart', direction: 'ASC'}] ,

        grouper: {
            groupFn: function(item) {
                return item.get('convDate');
            },
            sortProperty: 'groupSorterProp',
            direction: "ASC"
        }

    }
});
```

---

View

```
Ext.define("XXX.view.EventsList", {

    extend: "Ext.dataview.List",
    alias: "widget.eventslist",
    config: {

        loadingText: "Loading Events...",
        emptyText: '<div class="notes-list-empty-text">No notes found.</div>',
        onItemDisclosure: false,
        itemTpl:    '<div class="list-item-title">\n\
                        <div class="list-item-title-row">\n\
                            <div class="bl-hours"><span class="timetable-hours">{DateTimeStartConverted}</span></div>\n\
                               <div class="bl-event">{EventTitle}</div>\n\
                        </div>\n\
                     </div>',
        grouped: true

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a error when calling `data()` because this method does not exist. Use [setData](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-method-setData) instead.

**Update**

You should bind yourself to the store 'load' event

```
populateViewsAfterLogIn: function (){
    var me = this,
        store = Ext.getStore('Events2');
    debugger

    me.getEventsList().setStore(store );
    store.load();
}
```

`setData()` is expecting a array and not a store instance. In your case you should bind the store to the list before loading it. Sencha will then care about anything.

Comment: You were right data() throw an error, so I have tried with myEventsList.setData(storeEvents2); with no success... do you have any idea what am I doing wrong here? thanks

Comment: Thanks for your edit, your code work great and I was able to load the store in the List. Once again thanks for your support!